# Extraction of details from Json Issue

Tags: asp.net, json, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to Fetch the of status and unmappedstatus from JSON as marked in the code attached below. I tried but I am unable to do it. Any help is appreciable. Thank you.

Please find the code attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhsVN.png)

Please find the error code shown below:

```
string responseString = "";
Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string MerchantKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MERCHANT_KEY"];
string SALT = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SALT"];
string MerchantId = MerchantTransactionId;

input.Add("key", MerchantKey.ToString());
input.Add("command", "verify_payment");
input.Add("var1", MerchantId.ToString());
input.Add("hash", GenerateHash(MerchantTransactionId));


ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://info.payu.in/merchant/postservice.php?form=2");
string postData = "key=" + MerchantKey.ToString() + "&command=verify_payment&var1=" + MerchantId.ToString() + "&hash=" + GenerateHash(MerchantId);
//string postData = "key=Tn1kDH&command=verify_payment&var1=200700001&hash=" + GenerateHash();
var data1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = data1.Length;
request.Method = "POST";

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse orderResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

orderData = ParseResponse(orderResponse);
JObject RequestBodyData = JObject.Parse((string)orderData.SelectToken("transaction_details"));
```

Also find the main error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J06X6.png)

Find the response [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CFSa.png)

Comment: I tried converting json into string but unable to get the solution

Comment: How did you get these properties' values? Do you have any error messages or provide your code?  
The structure in the picture looks not a valid JSON format.

Comment: @jsotola  I have editied the question please check

Comment: @WENJUNCHI please check I hv edited the question

Comment: better ... i do not see any error code ... please add the error code as text, not a link to unknown places

Comment: @jsotola Its not taking to unknown place, its just an image I hv attached

Comment: The  orderData.SelectToken method return an object, cannot convert it to string using (string)obj.
If you want to convert the obj to string, you can override the ToString method, and call obj.ToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JToken.SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) method from Newtonsoft.Json returns [JToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) object. JToken object can be converted to string using explicit conversion operator only when value representing by this JToken object is a primitive type (e.g. string or number).

In the described scenario JToken object represents the entire "transaction_details" JSON object. As result, the explicit conversion to string returns corresponding "Can not convert Object to String." exception.

If there is a real need to get a string representation of "transaction_details" JSON object, then as it was mentioned in comments, the [JToken.ToString](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString.htm) method can be used.

> JToken.ToString Method
> Returns the indented JSON for this token.

But if the real task is to get values of "status" and "unmappedstatus" fields, then these values can be queried directly from the existing JToken object.

```
var status = (string)orderData.SelectToken("transaction_details.status");
var unmappedstatus = (string)orderData.SelectToken("transaction_details.unmappedstatus");
```

OR

```
var transactionDetails = orderData.SelectToken("transaction_details");
var status = (string)transactionDetails.SelectToken("status");
var unmappedstatus = (string)transactionDetails.SelectToken("unmappedstatus");
```